# How do I convert datetime hour part from 24 hour format to 12 hour format in SSIS expression?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl, integration

I want to convert the current time's hour part from 24-hour format to 12-hour format. I need output in SSIS expression as the below query gives in SSMS.

```
SELECT '0'+CAST(DATEPART(HH,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
   + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),109)),1,2))
```

**Output:**

01AM

Actually, this was an example to show what is required. I'm loading data from the database table to an Excel sheet in SSIS and to name the sheet, I have added the expression:

```
\\\\Filespace1\\ITCommon\\Data Validation\\Data ValidationComplex Care\\Daily_Report_" 
   + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("hh",GetDate())+"_" 
   + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) 
   + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) 
   + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2)+".xls"
```

and I want to get the file name as: Daily_Report_01PM_20220414.xls instead of Daily_Report_13_20220414.xls. Hope you understand my question.

Comment: Note, you should **never** use `varchar` without a size as the default size might be unexpected.

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem; Date and time values don't have a format. Why do you "need" to change the value within SSIS to be 12 hour "format"? This means that the value **must** be a string, *not* a date and time value.

Comment: I find it easiest to do it in a script task. Something like DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hh:mm_tt");

Comment: @KeithL Please answer in the "Answer portion" below so this may help others.

Answer (score 1):

I use script task to parse dates. Something like...

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hh:mm_tt");
```